# Python Mistake - Number of letters in name

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

Write a program that checks how long a name is. The program should take a name as input from the user.

If the name has 3 or fewer letters, your program should work like this:

**Enter your name: Lin
Hi Lin, you have a short name.**

If the name has between 4 and 8 letters (inclusive), your program should work like this:

**Enter your name: Jimmy
Hi Jimmy, nice to meet you.**

Otherwise, if the name has more than 8 letters, your program should work like this:

**Enter your name: Yaasmeena
Hi Yaasmeena, you have a long name.**

Here's my attempt but it always returns "Hi XXXXXXX, you have a short name" regardless of the length.

```
Name = input('Enter your name: ')

if Name.count('Name') >= int(3):
  print ('Hi', 'Name', ',', 'nice to meet you.') 

elif Name.count('Name') <= int(3):
  print ('Hi', 'Name', ',', 'you have a short name.')

elif Name.count('Name') > int(8):
  print ('Hi', 'Name', ',', 'you have a long name.')
```

Comment: `.count` is not how you get the length of a string. Try `len(...)`...

Comment: `3` is already an `int`.

Comment: First of all, what is the question here? Second, your `if` will never get to the third option since the first two are almost mutually exclusive. Change the order to check `> 8` first, then `> 3` then <= 3.

Comment: As a bonus, you should consider what happens if someone enters just a bunch of spaces for name - so they tap the space bar a couple of times and then hit enter.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `len(name)` and you don't need `int(3)` as `3` is already an integer. Your check should look like this:

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) >= 3:
   # do stuff
```

I changed `Name` to `name` as this is the standard convention of variable naming in Python.

Comment: Heres the updated code, it won't work for longer than 8, it just says nice to meet you if > 3

name = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) <= 3:
  print ('Hi',name, ', you have a short name.') 
elif len(name) >= 3:
  print ('Hi',name, ', nice to meet you.')
elif len(name) > 8:
  print ('Hi',name, ', you have a long name.')

Comment: Think about the order of your comparison. If something is bigger than `8`, it is also bigger or equal to `3`. Use that to change the order in which you compare the lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You code will not behave as you expect.  In addition to using len, use string formatting.  Try re-arranging your if statements as follows:

```
name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) > 8:
  print 'Hi {}, you have a long name.'.format(name)
elif len(name) > 3:
  print 'Hi {}, nice to meet you.'.format(name)
else:
  print 'Hi {}, you have a short name.'.format(name)
```

or you could factor it like this:

```
name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
greeting = 'Hi {}, '.format(name)

if len(name) > 8:
  statement = 'you have a long name.'
elif len(name) > 3:
  statement = 'nice to meet you.'
else:
  statement = 'you have a short name.'

print '{}{}'.format(greeting, statement)
```

Comment: Avoid doing the work for someone that is clearly asking a homework question. Instead provdiing hints helps them understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(a) <= int(3):
  print ('Hi', a+ ',', 'you have a short name.')

elif len(a) <= int(8):
 print ('Hi', a+ ', nice to meet you.') 

elif len(a) > int(8):
  print ('Hi', a+ ', you have a long name.')
```

Comment: This code might work but it doesn't explain why OP's doesn't.